# Edwin can't learn Protection From Magical Weapons; why?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

Edwin is a conjurer, which means he is opposed to the *Divination* school, but `Protection From Magical Weapons` is a spell from the *Abjuration* school.

I have the scroll in my inventory, it is not memorized, and I don't have the option to write it.

What's going on with my Edwin boi ?

Comment: @Raj Yep that was it (reached maximum number of spells).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(writing this up as an answer)

I don't recall running in to this issue myself, but your party member probably reached the maximum number of spells for that level. You may be able to get around this, by temporarily increasing their intelligence (e.g by using a potion or wand that increases that attribute).

https://forums.beamdog.com/discussion/61730/protection-from-magical-weapons